# InvocationTargetException isn't showed on Java Console [Applet]

Tags: java, applet, jna

I created an applet to print using [jna library](http://jna.java.net/).
When I run it, I  receive the exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.
When I look the Java Console, the exception won't be there.

```
Java Plug-in 10.4.1.255
Using JRE version 1.7.0_04-b22 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
```

My source code:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import java.applet.Applet;
class Impressora extends Applet {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        try {
            Mp2032 lib = (Mp2032) Native.loadLibrary("mp2032", Mp2032.class);
            System.out.println(lib.IniciaPorta("COM3"));
            System.out.println(lib.ConfiguraModeloImpressora(5));
            System.out.println(lib.BematechTX("teste\n"));
            System.out.println(lib.BematechTX("teste\n"));
            System.out.println(lib.AcionaGuilhotina(1));
            System.out.println(lib.FechaPorta());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public interface Mp2032 extends StdCallLibrary {
    public int AcionaGuilhotina(int modo);
    public int AjustaLarguraPapel(int largura);
    public int AutenticaDoc(String texto, int tempo);
    public int BematechTX(String texto);
    public int CaracterGrafico(String texto, int lenght);
    public int ComandoTX(String comando, int length);
    public int ConfiguraCodigoBarras(int altura, int largura, int posicao, int fonte, int margem);
    public int ConfiguraModeloImpressora(int modelo);
    public int IniciaPorta(String porta);
    public int FechaPorta();
    public int FormataTX(String texto, int tipoLetra, int italico, int sublinahdo, int expandido, int enfatizado);
}
```

My index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <applet width=300 height=300 code="Impressora" ARCHIVE="ImpressoraAssinada.jar"></applet>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My key generation:

```
cd C:\path\to\dir\Impressora
keytool -genkey -dname "cn=Impressora, ou=XX, o=XXX, l=city, s=RS c=BR" -alias ImpressoraKey -keystore C:\ImpressoraKey -storepass passwd -validity 7300
jarsigner -keystore C:\ImpressoraKey -storepass passwd -signedjar ImpressoraAssinada.jar Impressora.jar ImpressoraKey
keytool -export -keystore C:\ImpressoraKey -storepass passwd -alias ImpressoraKey -file Impressora.x509
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955790/applet-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception