# Embedding Java applet in html5

Tags: java, html, swing, applet, invocationtargetexception

I'm trying to embed a Java applet that I just made into an HTML 5 compliant page. I'm using the following tag to embed the .jar file:

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" height="300" width="550">
      <param name="code" value="MainClassName" />
      <param name="archive" value="MyJarFileName.jar" />
      Applet failed to run.  No Java plug-in was found.
</object>
```

The java applet will try to run but stop with:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

I'm having trouble finding what is the cause of this error. My .jar file will run fine on its own. The main class extends `JApplet`, which contains a frame, which contains a JPanel.

What is causing this error?

Comment: this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955790/applet-java-lang-reflect-invocationtargetexception

Comment: 1) `InvocationTargetException` is often caused by the applet not being declared `public`. 2) Use `deployJava.js` to write the element. 3) If the applet is available at a public URL where we can visit it, supply the URL. 4) *"extends JApplet, which contains a frame, which contains a JPanel."*  What exactly DYM by 'frame'?  An applet should not typically be launching a `JFrame` or `Frame`.

Comment: That was exactly it, my main constructor was private. Now I don't get an error but it wont load. The example that i saw in https://eyeasme.com/Shayne/HTML5_APPLETS/Sample.java does the same thing I did: create a Frame from the Main class which extends JApplet

Comment: I just threw it up here:https://dl.dropbox.com/u/38434655/index.html

Comment: @nwnoga: Please edit your question to cite your sources and include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the current problem. It's unlikely that anyone will endure dropbox see your code. Also consider [tag:javawebstart] and a [hybrid](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12449949/230513) applet/application.

Comment: Try viewing the Java console to see if there are any errors. Don't ask additional questions if the main question has been sufficiently answered...